# Parenthesis in the middle of nowhere in Javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube

I'm looking through some of the JavaScript code of YouTube and I've come across something I've never seen before. Here's the relevant bit of code:

```
for (var e = window.ytbuffer.queue, a = 0; 5 > a && a < e.length; a++) {
    var g = e[a],
        h = g.target || g.srcElement;
    (0, m.Hf)((0, m.Af)({
            a: "buffer_events",
            event_index: a,
            clientX: g.clientX,
            clientY: g.clientY,
            localName: h.localName,
            className: h.className,
            id: h.id,
            page_name: (0, m.v)("PAGE_NAME")
        }))
}
window.document.removeEventListener ? window.document.removeEventListener("click",
    window.ytbuffer.enqueueEvent, !1) : window.document.detachEvent("onclick", window.ytbuffer.enqueueEvent);
(0, m.Wc)("ytbuffer")
```

What I'm wondering is, what does (0, m.Hf) actually do? I know parenthesis can be used as grouping for mathematical operations, but then I wouldn't expect to see a comma there, and I know that parenthesis can be used to surround function arguments, but there's no function name.

Thanks,

YM

Edit: I used Chrome's inspector on the page and found that m is undefined. This has made me even more confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parens with comma separated expressions inside will return the last expression. So:

`(2, 3, 4) + 1`  returns 5

So, instead of doing:

```
alert("Hello World!!")
```

You could do:

```
(prompt, alert)("Hello World!!")
```

Because `(prompt, alert)`  returns `alert`, right?

That's exactly what's happening in that code

`(0, m.Hf)(...)` is just calling the `m.Hf()` method, just with some nesting.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Does it by any chance return the last defined value? That'd explain the purpose here, to call m.Hf() OR do nothing depending on whether m.Hf is defined, right? Does it work like that?

Comment: No, it always returns the last param (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comma_operator). I think that code for some reason was obfuscated intentionally. Using `0` as a function would be an error.